# How to checkout project in my local machine(windows 8) from git repo and i am using bitbuket & source tree

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, git-checkout

I want checkout project from git repo. and i am using bitbucket repo.

i am using this command `git clone https://test@bitbucket.org/abc/xyz.git` and cloning start

see attached:
[image]

**but i don't know this cloning/checkout is where to store in my local**

And i am also try using source-tree but i don't how to checkout project quickly

see attached :

[image]

then when i click on **Clone** then cloning process start but still cloning 5 - 6 hour.

please help me i want to checkout project quickly

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do a clone using SourceTree and BitBucket:

1. Choose Clone / New from the menu bar.
   The system displays the Clone / Add Create Repository dialog.
2. Enter a Source Path / URL.
   You can enter the URL for a remote repository on Bitbucket here.  Try entering the URL for your bb101repo, for example:
   https://tutorials@bitbucket.org/tutorials/bb101repo 
   The system requests a username password.
3. Enter your password and press Login.
4. Press Clone.
   SourceTree returns you to the main window.

The bookmarks list is only for local repositories; you'll need to clone from a hosted repository or create a local repository to add to this list.

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Sourcetree+Git+GUI+on+Windows

If it's taking a really long time to clone, maybe it's related to your internet connection? You could try to do a speed test to verify (http://www.speedtest.net).